# Copy and paste snippet code between local and remote PC with vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code, and I need to copy a code snippet (of my Vue app) from my PC to another PC on my remote server. Both are using VS Code.

I tried `CTRL-C` with the following code in my PC:

```html
 <template v-slot:[`header.destino`]="{ header }">
                <span class="text-h3 font-weight-black black--text">{{
                  header.text.toUpperCase()
                }}</span>
</template>
```

When I type `CTRL-V` on my server PC with VS Code, initally the code is equal.
But when I save, it becomes:

```html
<template v-slot:[&#x60;header.nome_para_chamar&#x60;]="{ header }">
                <span class="text-h3 font-weight-black black--text">
                  {{
                  header.text.toUpperCase()
                  }}
                </span>
</template>
```

The backtick character **`** becomes `&#x60;`

What is the problem here?

Comment: I think it may be caused by the inconsistency between the file encoding of the server and the pc. Try to set the encoding to `utf-8`. If the result remains unchanged, you can only temporarily modify the backticks to ES5 syntax like `<template v-slot:['header.destino']="{ header }">`

Comment: No, I have both with utf-8. It happends now in my local PC, after I update package.json to latest versions of the packages of my project